# setImageresource in android - how to use it for many pictures in a loop

Tags: java, android

it is a rather simple question. I have 5 imageViews and 5 images in drawable folder. ImageViews are named `imageView1`...`imageView5` and images are named `image1`...`image5`

I want how can I write the following elegantly:

```
  imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1)
  imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2)
  imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3)
  imageView4.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4)
  imageView5.setImageresource(R.drawable.image5)
```

As you understand, there are not just 5 imageViews, but there are many more and I want to write it in a loop. I am having problems because `R.drawable.imageX` is integer not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //Declaration 

 private int[] tabDrawables = new int[] {
                    R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,
                    R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,
                    R.drawable.image5};



     private ArrayList<ImageView> listImages = new ArrayList<ImageView>();


    //When you find your images on the onCreate method
    //add all images here

    listImages.add(imageView1);
    listImages.add(imageView2);
        ...

    for (int i = 0; i < tabDrawables.length; i++) {
         listImages.get(i).setImageResource(tabDrawables[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. So in any way I cannot avoid declaring the array. Thought that it may be another sollution