# How to dynamically get R value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have to dynamically get some resources from the **R** file.

For example, let's say I have to dynamically generate `ImageView` and dynamically get a **drawable** to put inside it.

I don't know how many `ImageView` I have to generate; there may be 10, 50 or 100 so I have to do everything dynamically.

My main problem is to get dynamically the **drawable** from the **R** file.

Lets say I have this drawable:
**R.drawable.img1**
**R.drawable.img2**
**R.drawable.img3**
**R.drawable.img4**

I should do something like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.img + i);            
    }
```

How can I "build" this line of code: `R.drawable.img + i`

How can I reach my goal?

Comment: ``iv.setImageResource(int);`` think how to use int

Comment: I think you can set tag with imageview runtime?did you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147437/setimageresource-in-android-how-to-use-it-for-many-pictures-in-a-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first make sure your image is `jpg` or `png`

You can try with this

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
      ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
      int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/img "+i.replace(".jpg", ""), null,context.getPackageName());
      iv.setImageResource(imageResource);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   final int []imageArray=
           {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3};


           final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int i=0;
            public void run() {
            //randomimg.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);

            //hEAR CREATE dynamic image view and set image resource 
               i++;
                if(i>imageArray.length-1)
                {
                i=0;    
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);  //for interval...
             }

           };
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

put above code in your activity. and set image resource it work for me.

Comment: why you calling `Handler `?

Comment: in above code where i put comment , you put your dynamic imageview and set it's image.